# What the מאירי holds on חזקה

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, chazaka

Where are places in the Gemara (or anywhere else) that we see the way the מאירי holds when it comes to חזקה.
Preferably חזקה דמעיקרה but all sources are helpful. Thanks!

Comment: There are so many issues related to Chazaka that I don't know what you want. Unbinding VTC as too broad. This isn't a binary issue

Comment: Are you finally consent to tell us where is this Meiri, your way of speaking is so laconic that we can not know what you mean.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: There really shouldn't be any need for paragraph answers, mekorot should be: source destination, new line, source destination.. Etc. but as stated above I'm looking for חזקה דמעיקרה I find hard to believe that if the me'iri discusses it (I'm not sure he does, but if he does) that he holds differently in many different cases. Therefore only 1-4 sources would be required to answer this question and 1-2 paragraphs at most

Comment: We can indicate the [Kessef Nivhar](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32803&st=&pgnum=14&hilite=), see in this reference from page 14 to page 49, you will find a whole program to 'visit' the fascinating and extended subject of Hazaka. It is the kind of subject that we may not pretend to understand without a minimum of knowledge. If I remember, you cited Gemara **Niddah**. There is important Gemara in **Hulin**, in Sotah, Baba Metsia, Baba Batra, Know you the books Shev Shmaatata and Shaarey Yosher? זיל גמור, and we will continue the discussion later.

Comment: My question is places the me'iri discusses chazaka, are these all places he does or just chazaka places?

Comment: The Meiri wrote a lot and has commented entire Talmud

Comment: But not all and most likely most of his commentary is not on chazakah and even less is on חזקה דמעיקרה. If you don't know the answer that's 100% acceptable but the question is not a crazy long answer and it's totally valid. I'm looking for where the me'iri discusses חזקה דמעיקרה. I don't know how much he writes on it but I'm fairly positive it's not volumes and volumes. Therefore, if you know the answer please submit one and I'd be happy to upvote and check it off (assuming it's correct), otherwise there's no need to question the motives or validity of the question.